Sampling weights and K prototype clustering
Can I use sample weights for k-prototype clustering? My dataset have weights for each observation, in this case, how can I change the code to incorporate the weights. Also, I am not sure if sampling weights make any change to clustering. I looked for different sources but could not get the answer.
I looked into the Chatgpt , it shows me this code:
clusters = kproto.fit_predict(X, categorical=list(range(n_cat)), weights=weights)
